# node.js with browser-based API

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, browser

I have a javascript file that is normally used in a web browser using a script tag. It is a self-executing function that seems to put an object on the window (the window is passed in).

What would be the cleanest way to use it from node.js on the server?

Thanks,

Gareth

Comment: Are you looking to: (a) use this file from Node without making any changes? (b) make a separate version of it that will work in Node? or (c) make a single version of the file that's friendly to both browser and Node?

Comment: It would need to be the same file, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Okay, that eliminates one of the three choices. Are you willing/able to make modifications to this file to make it work (c), or do you have to use the original file as-is (a)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant same file, no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all it does is add attributes to `window`, and you want to get those back out, you can create a global called `window`:

```
global.window = {};
require('theLibrary');
// now do something with global.window.theThingItAdded
```

However, if the library was written for the browser, it's possible that it still won't run because it wants to use the DOM. In that case, you might want to look into [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), which aims to give you a spec-compliant DOM inside Node.

(If you're using jsdom, I think that you would use it *instead* of the `global.window` bit above -- I think jsdom does that for you, but with a more full-featured window object. I haven't actually used jsdom, though, so I don't know for sure.)